# Setting up file download feature in an android app (with kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

In order to provide a file download feature in one of my android apps, I followed some tutorial and am now testing a trial app, with the following problem. Here is the code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var downloadID:Long = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val urlStr = "https://example.net/SomeFolder/SomeFile.mp3"

        // Set the local file.
        val mydir = applicationContext.getDir("MyDownLoadDir", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val dldFile = File(mydir, "downloadAudio.mp3")

        var request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlStr))
            .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(dldFile))
        var dldMgr = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        println("Trace before dldMgr.enqueue")
        downloadID = dldMgr.enqueue(request)

        var brdCstRcvr = object:BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
                val id = p1?.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1)
                if (id == downloadID)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Download Completed !!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        registerReceiver(brdCstRcvr, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
    }
}
```

The app relies on `DownloadManager` to handle the file transfer, but the tutorial does not give much detail on the setting of the destination file.

It looks like the way I set my destination file is not right. Below is the error message I get:

```
I/System.out: Trace before dldMgr.enqueue
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/oftware.dnldtr: Accessing hidden method Lcom/msic/qarth/PatchStore;->createDisableExceptionQarthFile(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Z (blacklist, JNI)
E/oftware.dnldtr: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: me.soft.myapp, PID: 7769
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.soft.myapp/me.soft.myapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path /data/data/me.soft.myapp/app_MyDownLoadDir/downloadAudio.mp3
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
```

So my question is why is my destination file wrong?
(Unsupported path ..... in the error message)
And what is the correct way to set a destination file?

Edition to the original post:

I just noticed in the `DownloadManager` documentation this contents:

**By default, downloads are saved to a generated filename in the shared download cache and may be deleted by the system at any time to reclaim space.**

(Otherwise it should be *EXTERNAL_STORAGE*)

This may explain the issue I am facing.

As a result (in my case) I should refrain from setting :

```
.setDestinationUri(someThing)
```

But in this case how do I know the name of the generated filename and how do I access it in the shared download cache.

Comment: /data/data/.. is an unsupported path. Its an app privat path unreachable for DownloadManager. /storage/emulated/0/Download would be supported. Better not use setDestinationUri but setDestinationInExternalDir with not a full path but just a public directory name like Download.

Comment: OK. Thanks. In this case I do not want to use external storage. Is it still OK to use setDestinationInExternalDir ?

Comment: You should first tell where you want the file to be stored as we cannot give an answer without that information.

Comment: I see. I want to store it internally inside the app.

Comment: ???? Where would that be? An app is no storage location to begin with.

Comment: My understanding is that by default DownloadManager.Request() will store it in some default cache. If I know how to get the file from there, then I should be able to put it to MyDownLoadDir/downloadAudio.mp3 as I was trying to do in my original code.

Comment: @blackapps. If I remove .setDestinationUri(someThing) from my code, then I can see the message: "Download Completed !!!". But I don't know the proper code to get the file. It would be very useful to know that.

Comment: Well tell where it landed.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed what I need to know. Since the only thing I see is "Download Completed !!!" I don't know where the actual file is and what its name is.

Comment: Ever heard of a Download directory? And never clicked on the notification? And in your code you can get an uri from the download manager.

Comment: Yes the problem is that when I go to the Download directory on my device I don't see the file. I presume I may be looking in a different place. About getting the uri from the download manager: How do you do that?

Comment: `My understanding is that by default DownloadManager.Request() will store it in some default cache. ` I think you are right. I did a test without specifying a destination and i could not find it i Download or Documents or other directory.

Comment: To get an uri after download you should register a broadcast receiver after the enqueue. `registerReceiver( onDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));`

Comment: `private BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() { ....` You can there obtain an uri and the file name (its unchanged). An uri path looks like content://downloads/all_downloads/964

Comment: @blackapps. I have already registered a broadcast receiver and this is how I get the message "Download Completed !!!". But there I do not see any URI or file name. I have looked at BroadcastReceiver->onReceive 2 arguments but found nothing, I must have missed some detail.

Comment: In onReceive you can get uri and name from your downloadmanager instance. Android Studio will tell you all available functions so choose. I dont know them anymore by head and i'm laying under a palm tree right now.

Comment: @blackapps. Do you know exactly how?